# Is getting address of rvalue reference before move considered safe?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I'm playing around Move Semantics and [r|l]value references to learn how to use them in real-world programs. Consider following code:

```
// Item is a heavy class having move ctor and assignment but no copy. 
std::map<std::string, Item*> lookup;
std::forward_list<Item> items;
void FooClass::addItem(Item&& d) {
    if (lookup.find(d.getName()) == lookup.end()) {
        lookup[d.getName()] = &d;    //<== not safe after move?
        items.push_front(std::move(d));
    }
}
```

I'm getting address of an `Item&&` and store it in a pointer. Then move data that to a `std::forward_list` (`items`). I assume calling move assignment does not affect address of object. Is that correct? Though content of `d` is no more valid after move. That is content of lookup table (`lookup`) is incorrect.

I'm assuming that I have to re-order a) adding lookup item and b) move actual data. Above code  is not sane. Is this correct?

Also I can't see why do I have to say `std::move` there. Compiler should know that `d` is a rvalue reference. So it should call `std::forward_list<T>::push_front(T&&)` and move assignment...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    lookup.[d.getName()] = &d;    //<== not safe after move?
```

This is completely unsafe, but not just because of the move. Contrary to your question's title, you are not taking the address of an rvalue reference, you are taking the address of an lvalue, but one which is probably going to go out of scope soon after the function returns, which will leave a dangling pointer.   Consider:

```
FooClass f;
f.addItem( Item() );
```

This adds the address of a temporary to the map, so if you ever dereference the pointer your program has undefined behaviour, the epitome of unsafe.

The move on the next line might make things worse, because the object referred to by the pointer in the map might get modified by the move, leaving a pointer to a moved-from `Item` in the map, but that's nothing compared to the undefined behaviour that results from it going out of scope after the function returns.

It's trivial to make the code safe, so there is no reason to write it the way you have done.

```
    items.push_front(std::move(d));
    auto& item = items.front();
    lookup[item.getName()] = &item;
```

Now the pointer in the map refers to an object which is not about to go out of scope.  The pointer will be valid as long as the element is in the `forward_list`.

Comment: Given that pos == lookup.end(), does providing it as a hint really help?

Comment: @Nevin, Oops, I meant to use `lower_bound` and check if the element was found, but forgot to finish that bit of the answer! I'll just delete it, can't be bothered to show the correct form now ;)

Comment: I think `lookup[d.getName()] = &items.front()` is not sane too ;)

Comment: @soroush, why? As I said, that pointer will be valid until you erase that element from `items`, which is guaranteed to be after the function returns and is in your control, whereas `d` is _likely_ to be destroyed after the function returns, and is not necessarily in your control.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I'm supposing that `d` is moved, then it no longer have its old name...

Comment: @soroush: That's not how movement works. All movement is is calling a different constructor/assignment operator based on whether the given value is an rvalue or lvalue reference. It's the difference in the copy/move constructors and assignments that cause copying or movement. Movement doesn't destroy the existing object or "transfer" it or anything like that. It just allows the possibility to make non-const changes to the given object, such as stealing resources and such. The object *still exists* after it is moved from.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Yes, if `d.getName()` returns something different when `d` has been moved from then it won't work. I lazily copied&pasted the original `items[d.getName()]` code. I've updated the answer to get the name from the list element now.

Answer (score 1):

I would get rid of `items` and change `lookup` to store `Item` by value, as in:

```
using Lookup = std::map<std::string, Item>;
Lookup lookup;

void addItem(Item&& d)
{ lookup.insert(std::pair<std::string const&, Item&&>{d.getName(), std::move(d)}); }
```

Comment: Use `std::make_pair(d.getName(), std::move(d))` instead of manually specifying the complete type of the pair!  Or, at the very least, use `Lookup::value_type{d.getName(), std::move(d)}`.

Comment: Or better yet, use `emplace(d.getName(), std::move(d))`, it's less typing and more efficient

Comment: I was using pair<string const&, Item&&> because I wanted a pair of references; I don't want to incur the copying/moving cost unless the element is actually going to be inserted into the map.  I don't believe either Lookup::value_type (which was my original solution) or emplace will delay that, will it?